# How can I create a 'wrapper' view which factors out common outer XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In a WPF project I am creating a wizard comprising of many steps. Each step has its own view. Currently, each view has the same outer XAML elements, like a `TextBlock` for the title of the step, but different content below that.

So, for example a typical view would look like:

**STEP X VIEW**

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Step X text goes here"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- CONTENT OF STEP X GOES HERE -->
    </Grid>     
</Grid>
```

What I would like to do is be able to 'factor out' the common outer XAML for each step into another view and just place the content of each step as the content of that new factored out view. That way, I can avoid the repetition of the same outer XAML, and if I decide to change the implementation of each step title, I only have to do it in one place.

I'm sure `ContentPresenter` is the part of the solution. So, something like:

**WRAPPERVIEW:**

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Step X text goes here"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentPresenter Content="Content of Step X ??????"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

My questions are:

1) Is my implementation of `WrapperView` the right way to go?

2) What is the binding for the `ContentPresenter` content property in `WrapperView`?

3) How can I customise the `Text` of the `TextBlock` for each step using `WrapperView`?

4) How can I get the client XAML using `WrapperView` for the XAML of any step view to look like.

So, using `WrapperView` for StepXView ,

**New STEP X VIEW**

```xml
<Grid>
    <WrapperView TitleText ="Step X Title Text">
        <!-- XAML for Step X View -->
    </WrapperView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a good intuition about using a `ContentPresenter`. To me, it looks exactly like you need a `HeaderedContentControl`, which is a templatable `Control` which handles both a `Header` and a `Content` property.

Although you could directly use `HeaderedContentControl`, I find it clearer to inherit from it in case you want to customize it further later:

```cs
public class WrapperView : HeaderedContentControl { }
```

And in your XAML, you can template it and use it as you wish:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:WrapperView}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:WrapperView">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <local:WrapperView Header ="Step X Title Text">
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Blue"/>
        </local:WrapperView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The key here is the use of `TemlateBinding` which answers your second question.

To make it even cleaner, you could move this `Style` away from your `Window.Resources` and set it in `Themes\Generics.xaml` so that the `Style` gets applied by default.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help. Very much appreciated. I apologise for not referencing your name directly, but it doesn't show up when I type @ for some reason.

Comment: @Cleve it only works to reference the name of someone already in the comments thread - since you were the first comment, no one showed up:)